# Programatically Create Layout to be displayed on an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-alertdialog, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I want to dynamically create a LinearLayout.

How do I set it to display in my AlertDialog?

I've seen examples where the layout was created via XML and inflated to show, but I do not want to create XML layouts when I can do it dynamically.

I'm restricted to API 16 = Android 4.1.2

This is a button on my activity...

```
public void TestOnClick() {
    Button test_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_test);
    test_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(v.getContext());

            //Create a TextView to add to layout
            TextView textview = new TextView(v.getContext());
            textview.setText("My Test");
            layout.addView(textview);

            //Add abunch of other items to the layout
            //blah blah blah

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
            builder.setView(layout);
            builder.setNeutralButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Share some code please

Comment: @Roy see my code below

Comment: @Chairizky - Thank you for the response, but I want to display my custom layout (programmatically created and not via XML) in the AlertDialog rather than just display a message on the AlertDialog.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I had to do the following to achieve dynamically and programmatically creating a LinearLayout and displaying that layout onto an AlertDialog:

```
public void TestOnClick() {
    Button test_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_test);
    test_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Create LinearLayout Dynamically
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(v.getContext());

            //Setup Layout Attributes
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layout.setLayoutParams(params);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            //Create a TextView to add to layout
            TextView textview = new TextView(v.getContext());
            textview.setText("My Text");

            //Create Spinner
            Spinner spinner = new Spinner(v.getContext());
            String[] string_list = new String[]{"Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, string_list);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinner.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            //Create button
            Button button = new Button(v.getContext());
            button.setText("My Button");
            button.setWidth(100);
            button.setHeight(50);

            //Add Views to the layout
            layout.addView(textview);
            layout.addView(spinner);
            layout.addView(button);

            //Create AlertDialog Builder
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());

            //Give the Dialog a Title
            builder.setTitle("Results");

            //Set the Dynamically created layout as the Dialogs view 
            builder.setView(layout);

            //Add Dialog button that will just close the Dialog
            builder.setNeutralButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            //Show the custom AlertDialog
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to apply dialog theme to an activity,simply modify the  element in the AndroidManifest.xml file by adding the android:theme attribute like this:

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Doing so will make the activity appear as a dialog..

Further,if you need to hide the activity title from displaying..add this line in OnCreate method of your activity

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

thats all,upvote if this helps you ...
[Visit This Page](http://www.ashif.me)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean is like make AlertDialog like this?

[image]

put this on your import

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Context;
```

then add this code

```
final Context context = this;   

Button test_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_test);
test_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {

   AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
    context);

   alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Quit");

   alertDialogBuilder
    .setMessage("Are you sure want to Quit?")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
      // if this button is clicked, close
      // current activity
     menu.this.finish();
     }
      })
    .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
      // if this button is clicked, just close
      // the dialog box and do nothing
      dialog.cancel();
     }
    });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
   }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that is just using the alerdialog setMessage. I want to be able to display my dynamically customized layout on the AlertDialog.